# Pagination in Amazon DynamoDB using Boto

Tags: python, boto, amazon-dynamodb

How do I paginate my results from DynamoDB using the Boto python library? From the Boto API documentation, I can't figure out if it even has support for pagination, although the DynamoDB API does have pagination support.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Boto does have support for "pagination" like behavior using a combination of "ExclusiveStartKey" and "Limit". For example, to paginate `Scan`.

Here is an example that should parse a whole table by chunks of 10

```
esk = None

while True:
    # load this batch
    scan_generator = MyTable.scan(max_results=10, exclusive_start_key=esk)

    # do something usefull
    for item in scan_generator:
        pass  # do something usefull
    # are we done yet ?
    else:
        break;

    # Load the last keys
    esk = scan_generator.kwargs['exclusive_start_key'].values()
```

EDIT:

As pointed out by @garnaat, it is possible that I misunderstood your actual goal. The above suggestion allows you to provide pagination like SO does for questions for example. No more than 15 per pages.

If you just need a way to load the whole result set produced by a given `Scan`, Boto is a great library and already abstracts this for you with no need for black magic like in my answer. In this case, you should follow what he (@garnaat) advises. Btw, he is the author of Boto and, as such, a great reference for Boto related questions :)

Comment: Thanks, this works. I guess I was looking for how to get the exclusive_start_key. Btw you might have a dangling else in the code.

Comment: I know the "else" statement seems weird ;) But actually, it is triggered when the "for" loop did exactly 0 iterations. http://psung.blogspot.ca/2007/12/for-else-in-python.html

Comment: No, this was exactly what I was looking for, not loading the whole result set.

Comment: jtlebi, This is a nice answer, +1. However, could you, please, specify what is the type of MyTable? I looked into the code of oto.dynamodb2.table.Table and the scan() and query() (or query_2()) methods don't have "max_results" and "exclusive_start_key" arguments. What should I import and use in the role of MyTable?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the question but I think you are making it more difficult than it needs to be.  If you are using the layer2 DynamoDB interface in boto (the default) it handles the pagination for you.

So, if you want to do a query operation, you simply do this:

```
import boto

c = boto.connect_dynamodb()
t = c.get_table('mytable')
for item in t.query(hash_key='foo'):
    print item
```

This will automatically handle the pagination of results from DynamoDB.  The same would also work for a scan request.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand something, but this only allows to get all items one by one. What I want is to get the Nth "page", where a "page" has K items. Can this be done without having to read all (N-1) * K preceding Items (again and again, which is O(N^2)) ? Please, I would appreciate your answer how to obtain directly pageN.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, to accomplish what you've described you'd create a child resource using URL Path Parameters or URL Query String Parameters. Once configured (Integration Request -  body mapping and params mappings), you should be able to obtain specific results based on the params you pass through to the resource (and thus method).

I know this post is old, but may help those looking for help now.

Comment: This doesn't give me the full list of items. Another person is getting the same results as me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39355377/paginating-a-dynamodb-query-in-boto3

Comment: This is not how the [official examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.Python.04.html) use the `.query()` method! That documentation needs to be updated!

Comment: Also, doesn't seem to work. Can't find the query method source on github ether?

Answer (score 0):

there is a good chance you want something like this:

```
qms = tms.query(hash_key=415772421368583351, max_results=2, exclusive_start_key=None)
for i in qms:
    print i
lek = qms.last_evaluated_key
qms = tms.query(hash_key=415772421368583351, max_results=2, exclusive_start_key=lek)
for i in qms:
  print i
```

of course this is a silly example for demonstration.
The key here is to use `last_evaluated_key` not the `exclusive_start_key`