# How to user boto dynamodb scan with excluseive_start_key

Tags: boto, amazon-dynamodb

I want to do a scan on a table on dynamodb using boto, my problem is I want to paginate using the `max_results` and `exclusive_start_key`
Actually it looks like the only way to access the `LastEvaluatedKey` to pass it as `exclusive_start_key` is to manually keep track of primary keys and pass the last one as `exclusive_start_key`

But that is not my problem, my problem is I don't know what format (what object type) I should pass to `exclusive_start_key` it does not accept an int even when the table has an integer hash_key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation, Layer2 implementation of Scan expects either a list or a Tuple as a representation of the Primary Key.

- `(hash_key,)` for a single key table
- `(hash_key, range_key)` for a composed key table

Please note that there also is a (tricky) way to directly read the esk from the Scan generator in Boto.

Comment: You can find a detailed example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13164026/pagination-in-amazon-dynamodb-using-boto/13164275#13164275