# Paginating a DynamoDB query in boto3

Tags: python, aws-lambda, pagination, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

How can I loop through all results in a DynamoDB query, if they span more than one page? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13178258/526495) implies that pagination is built into the query function (at least in v2), but when I try this in v3, my items seem limited:

```
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
fooTable = dynamodb.Table('Foo')
response = fooTable.query(
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('list_id').eq('123')
)

count = 0

for i in response['Items']:
    count += 1

print count # Prints a subset of my total items
```

Comment: That should work. Try to `scan()` the entire table to make sure you are really supposed to get more items.

Comment: Thanks @joarleymoraes, but I tried exactly that and the count in the DynamoDB console is around 10x what boto3 is returning.

Comment: Is list_id string or integer ? Maybe you want Check that.

Comment: Any reason for using a `for loop` with a counter instead of `print len(response['Items'])`? BTW I have the same problem as you.

Comment: @JoãoAbrantes no reason, it's just sample code for the purpose of asking the question :)

Answer (score 2):

ExclusiveStartKey is the name of the attribute which you are looking for.
Use the value that was returned for LastEvaluatedKey in the previous operation.

The data type for ExclusiveStartKey must be String, Number or Binary. No set data types are allowed.

http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.query

Comment: Probably should have been more clear - I'm aware that I can paginate manually using `ExclusiveStartKey`. But in the linked answer, @garnaat (author of boto!) advised that it should be available out the box on the query function.

Comment: @Jonathan It sounds like @garnaat might be referring to something else. The documentation in the answer here is pretty explicit. You'll get a maximum of 1MB of data with each query and it is up to you, the application developer, to use the `ExclusiveStartKey` to fetch more.